# Set Primary Key for Table?

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, primary-key

```
        DataTable tbl =  view.ToTable();
        DataColumn[] pk = new DataColumn[table2.PrimaryKey.Length];

        var names = table2.PrimaryKey.Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < table2.PrimaryKey.Length; i++)
        {
            tbl.PrimaryKey[i] = tbl.Columns[names[i]];
        }



        tbl.PrimaryKey = pk;
```

I want to set all primary keys for the table, witch are saved in var names.

I have two indent. tables and I want to set the same primary keys...

Comment: So, whats your problem?

Comment: It won´t work...

Comment: So, update your question by adding more details. It will help you to get better answer.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are trying to achieve. You take the length of table1's PrimaryKey array to init tbl's PrimaryKey array, but then iterate over table2's PrimaryKey to populate tbl's, etc.
Please explain the purpose of this code so that people are able to help.

Comment: @NickS.: never say "doesn't work" without further explanation. You get an error, incorrect behaviour(in both cases explain and show stack trace) or your computer exploded? We have no idea

Comment: I have two indent. tables and I want to set the same primary keys...

Comment: @Rango hahahaah sorry, yes I get a System.IndexOutOfRangeExeption

Comment: omg, my fault :S thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use code like below. Note that I have commented your code within the loop and also the loop iterates over `names` rather than a DataTable primary keys.

*I have assumed that the DataTable `tbl` already contains all the columns whose column names are in the `names` array.*

```
    DataTable tbl =  view.ToTable();
    DataColumn[] pk = new DataColumn[table2.PrimaryKey.Length];

    var names = table2.PrimaryKey.Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();


    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        //tbl.PrimaryKey[i] = tbl.Columns[names[i]];
         pk[i] = tbl.Columns[names[i]]; 
    }


    tbl.PrimaryKey = pk;
```